# The angle sin returns a negative result for the acute angle

Tags: c#, math

I calculate the angles of a *triangle*, and I don't understand why I get a *negative angle* for some *acute angle*. For example:

```
var sin     = Math.Sin(4.45);
var radians = Math.Atan(sin);
var angle   = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
```

it return `sin = -0.965` and `angle = -44`.

When scientific calculator show `sin = 0.0775`

My triangle has such lengths `6.22`, `6.07` and `1.4` then there isn't option to had *negative angle*.

Comment: 4.45 radians isn't an acute angle though, or am I missing something?

Comment: `Sin(4.45 radians) == -0.965773` You are using radians when you think you're using degrees.

Comment: Let's convert initial `4.45` *radians* into *degrees*: `4.45/pi*180 ~ 255` degrees (please, note that `255 > 180`), a bit *strange triangle*

Comment: Please be aware that Math.Sin(double a) takes an radians angle and not a degree angle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Math.Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netframework-4.8) operates on radians.  You need to convert degrees into radians.

To convert degrees to radians multiply the angle by `/180`:

```
var sin = Math.Sin(4.45*Math.PI/180);
// output 0.07758909147106598
```

And the rest of your code should remain the same.

**Note:** if you just want to convert an angle in degrees to angle in radians you can use the formula above:

```
var degrees = 4.45;
var radians = degrees * Math.PI/180;
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's compute angles of the triangle with a help of [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

```
a**2 + b**2 - 2 * a * b * cos(gamma) == c**2
```

so

```
gamma = acos((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a * b))   
beta  = acos((a * a + c * c - b * b) / (2 * a * c))   
alpha = acos((c * c + b * b - a * a) / (2 * c * b))
```

now put *triangle lengths*

```
a = 6.22
b = 6.07
c = 1.40
```

into formulae above and you'll get *angles* (in *radians*, if you use c# `Math.Acos`)

```
 alpha = 1.5639 =  89.6 degrees
  beta = 1.3506 =  77.4 degrees
 gamma = 0.2270 =  13.0 degrees
 ------------------------------
                  180.0 degrees (let's check ourselves)
```

Another check is [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

```
 a / sin(alpha) == b / sin(beta) == c / sin(gamma) == 6.2201
```